# Securing an Angular 6 / 7 app by hiding/obfuscating the code

Tags: angular, security, angular6, obfuscation, angular7

Is there a way to obfuscate the production code of anAngular 6 (or 7) application. By production code i mean the dist folder generated after the command ng build --prod.
I have seen a software named Jscrambler but it is not free. 
How can i do that ?

thanks

Comment: Please keep in mind that [obscurity should never be the only security mechanism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity).

Answer (score 5):

When you use Angular CLI to build production code, your code is already minified and uglified (by UglifyJS) as said in the [Angular doc](https://angular.io/guide/deployment)

```
The --prod meta-flag engages the following build optimization features.

 - Ahead-of-Time (AOT) Compilation: pre-compiles Angular component templates.
 - Production mode: deploys the production environment which enables production mode.
 - Bundling: concatenates your many application and library files into a few bundles.
 - Minification: removes excess whitespace, comments, and optional tokens.
 - Uglification: rewrites code to use short, cryptic variable and function names.
 - Dead code elimination: removes unreferenced modules and much unused code.
```

If you didn't get code objuscation, you may need to check your *angular.json* file and make sure it contains the following settings:

```
"configurations": {
  "production": {
    "optimization": true,
```

Comment: why all the hating ?

Why negative -3 with no arguments ? What @Neo said seems correct.

Answer (score 4):

If you have Angular 7+, you can make use [@angular-builders/custom-webpack](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular-builders/custom-webpack) to utilize [javascript-obfuscator](https://github.com/javascript-obfuscator/webpack-obfuscator).  Note that I linked the custom-webpack for Angular 8+, assuming that you may have upgraded since a year ago.  If you need an Angular 7 version, they have a link on that page to the Angular 7 compatible version of [@angular-builders/custom-webpack](https://github.com/just-jeb/angular-builders/blob/7.x.x/packages/custom-webpack/README.md)